# Counting different numbers other than 0 (C) outputs different in different compilers

Tags: c

I am trying to find the number of distinct numbers from input which are not equal to 0. n is in 1-100 range. The numbers in the array are in the 0-600 range.
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/937/A
For this question, I wrote a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, count = 0, i;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int ar[n], ar2[601];
    memset(ar2, 0, 600 * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d ", &ar[i]);
        if (ar2[ar[i]] == 0)
            ar2[ar[i]] = 1;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 601; i++) {
        if (ar2[i] != 0)
            count++;
    }

    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

for the first test case (4 1 3 3 2) , it outputs the right answer 3 in ideone.com 's gcc 6.3, but outputs 4 in gcc 5.1 which is used at codeforces.

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent this ?
(I think it's because of memset, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: `for(i=1;i<601;i++){` -> Why are you using 1 and 601?

Comment: @EdHeal because I don't want 0 to be counted. And I want numbers before 600 to be counted. inputs are in the 0-600 range.

Comment: I have not yet read the problem statement, but why do you only initialize 600 entries of ar2 instead of 601?

Comment: You are reading `n` in `main`'s second line before initializing it.

Comment: @MathieuBorderé Oh, I completely forgot that. I'll fix that and try again. Also , n is in the 1-100 range.

Comment: @a3f Thanks! I always do that kind of stupid mistakes.

Comment: Do not make us follow a link to understand the problem.  Post the problem description directly.

Comment: @abelenky thanks. I'll do that in my next questions.

Comment: Perhaps edit this question

Comment: @edheal no. The input may be 5 1 600 600 600 600 and the answer would be 2.

Comment: Just realised that - had to re-read it

Comment: For what it's worth - I edited the question to format the code better and I moved the declaration of `ar` to where it is now. OP's original code had it after the call to `scanf`. I've corrected my error in the most recent edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining an  array of size `n` before the value of `n` has beed determined (note that you `scanf` the value of `n` later). This is undefined behaviour, such that different compilers may give different results, and even starting your program on your machine may give different results (including crashes).

instead of

```
int n, count = 0, i;
int ar[n];
...
```

write

```
int n, count = 0, i;

scanf("%d", &n);

int ar[n], ar2[601] = { 0 };
```

At least the malformed array should then be solved, and `ar2` is completely initialized with `0`. You can get rid of your `memset`, which initialized only 600 items (instead of 601) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quicker solution to the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    bool seen_number_before[601] = { false };
    int count = 0;
    seen_number_before[0] = true;

    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n); // Should do error checking here

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       int v;
       scanf("%d", v); // More error checking

       if (!seen_number_before[v]) // Not seen it before
          seen_number_before[v] = true; // Mark it as seen
          ++count;    // Add to the count
       }
     }
     printf("%d\n", count);
     return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: If you change `bool seen_number_before[601] = { false };` to `bool seen_number_before[601] = { true };`, you can delete `v != 0 &&`. But this does not answer OP’s question of why their code malfunctioned.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  - Good point about `true` . I would post this as a comment but it is code and too big.

Comment: Thanks Eric - The variable name `not_seen_number_before` could be improved - I leave that as an exercise to the reader

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code, from a[n] when n is not defined.
To check errors try compiling with some useful options:

```
gcc -Wall code.c -o code -g
```

the -Wall is for Warning all and the -g is used for debug on valgrind (useful tool to check memory leak and other errors).

Also I suggest you to name properly every var in your code, could helpful for a large size of code base.

This is my solution,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n, count = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int hash[600] = { 0 };

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
        if(a[i] != 0){
            hash[a[i]] = 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<600; i++){
        printf("%d ", hash[i]);
        if(hash[i] == 1) ++count;
    }

    printf("\n\n%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

it can be optimized in time, using only one for, and/or in memory by creating an hashset of int, and every int can store 32 bit and do some bitwise operations, so if the nth bit is 1, count++, otherwise don't do nothing.

Comment: (a) `a[i-1]` in the loop accesses `a[-1]` when `i` is 0. (b) `hash[599]` is not big enough as there are 600 possibilities for non-zero scores (1-600). (c) You suggest naming variables “properly” but then use `hash` for what is merely an array of flags, not hashes. (d) `a` is never freed. (e) There is no need for `a` at all, since each value read is used only once, so it does not need to be stored. (f) `int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(int))` is better as `int *a = malloc(n * sizeof *a)`, as this avoids errors in editing the type while neglecting to edit both occurrences.

Comment: Just a 1 minute of coding, don't take so personally. 
I agree at all, but (d) a is freed when the program is terminated.